# (substitute A Z list)

Tags: scheme

I heard the best way to do this is using the map feature, could someone please explain how I should go about using it? I read what my book said about it, but I didn't really understand how to implement it.

I basically want something that will substitute every A in a list with a Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `(map proc ls)` runs `proc` on every element in `ls`.  To replace items using map:

```
(map
  (lambda (x) 
    (if (equal? x 'whatever) 
        'replacement 
        x))
  '(whatever whatever something else))
```

which replaces `'whatever` with `'replacement`.  I think you can adapt the above to your homework.

Answer (score 2):

Map takes a function and a list, and returns a list of the function being applied to each member of the list. (map f '(1 2 3)) will return (f(1) f(2) f(3)). You already know that you want to use map on the list being input. What you need to figure out is how to make the function f determine if the current value is equal to A, and if so make it return Z. Let me know if you still don't get it.